# How to force RegexBuddy to forget the inputs?

Tags: regex

Testing a regular expression in RegexBuddy, I've entered a very long test to find matches. The thing is too complicated, so it will give months to highlight the occurrences.

Now, I can't stop the application in a correct way, and if I end the process and start the application again, I can't change anything: if I try to remove the regular expression or the text to test, it starts computing the occurrences again.

So is there a way to force RegexBuddy to forget what was entered?

I know I can probably reinstall it, but this happened to me several times, and I would have an easier/faster way to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question. From a [question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114/where-does-regexbuddy-store-its-working-data-between-uses/55182#55182), the keys to remove are located in the registry, in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JGsoft\RegexBuddy3\History`
.

Comment: in which case you should accept your own answer, so that this question can be considered complete by the system.

Comment: @DMA57361: I know. But with my actual reputation score, I can accept my own answers only two days after the answer is posted.

Comment: Ah! No, that's not a rep-score limit, that's a hard limit for all users (AFAIK), similar to the restrictions on starting a bounty. And I *always* forget about it for some reason. Apologies!